# Can I store scripts as values in a multi-dimensional array in gamemaker?

Tags: arrays, game-maker

I have an inventory system set up as a 2d array so that the first dimension is the equipped weapon and the 2nd dimension is how much ammo that weapon has. Since I wrote scripts for whenever the player uses each weapon, would it be possible to put these scripts in the array as a 3d dimension?
It would be set up something like this:

```
//I know this isn't correct gm syntax, I'm just trying to show the stucture of the array
inventory = [weapon[ammo[use_weapon()]]];
```

I want to do this so that I can create a script that easily calls the currently equipped weapon's script and I don't have to hard code in checks for every single weapon's index, script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any script to array like

```
array[0] = script_name;
```

and then run it like

```
var script = array[0];
script_execute(script);
```

in final, it can look like

```
var weapon = data_weapon[current_weapon];
var ammo = weapon[DATA_AMMO];
var script = ammo[DATA_ACTION];
script_execute(script);
```

where `DATA_AMMO`, `DATA_ACTION` is `Macros` and used instead `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

P.S. Of course, also you can pass other info to script (like `id` of shooter, or position and direction of shoot, etc)

```
script_execute(script, your_shooter.id);
```